# Unhandled rejection: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body when trying a ban command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I have the ban command running I get this error and I have `guildMember.ban` in there so I don't know why I'm getting this error.

```
DICT_TYPE_CONVERT: Only dictionaries may be used in a DictType  
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
```

Here is the code:

```js
const { version, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const errors = require("../events/error.js");
const moment = require("moment")
        
exports.run = async (client, message, [mention, ...reason]) => { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  if (message.mentions.members.size === 0)
    return message.reply("Please mention a user to ban.");

  if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS"))
    return message.reply("");
          
  let guildMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first())
          
  guildMember.ban(reason.join(" ")).then(member => {
    message.reply(`${member.user.username} was succesfully banned.`);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`guildMember.ban()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban) accepts an options object and `reason.join(" ")` is a string. You need to change it to an object having a key of `reason`:

```js
guildMember.ban({reason: reason.join(" ")})
```